# Convert from TIFF to PNG using Windows?

Tags: png, tiff, image-compression

Is there a way to convert all TIFF images to PNG using windows console or any simple tool. 
I renamed tags, but the problem now is file size. What are ways to compress files?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

imagemagick, it's CLI tool for image manipulation available for most major operating systems including Windows http://www.imagemagick.org/script/download.php

It's very simple to use it

```
convert in.tiff out.png
```

To convert and scale by 50%:

```
convert in.tiff -resize 50% out.png
```

[Here](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/resize/#percent) you can find full list of general commands

Comment: Convert all images in a folder with: gm mogrify -format png *.tiff

Answer (score 0):

TinyPng is great to compress png files, you can try that.
www.tinypng.com

Comment: My files are too large for your recomended tool